# PowerShell script for tab completion

Tags: powershell, tab-completion

In Word or Eclipse, as an example, it has an option to "auto-correct" a custom phrase like `sysout` into `System.out.println("");`. However, is there a script I could use to have this same function while typing in any other program?

For example, if I type `mcC` and press space, or hold Alt down while typing `mcC`, I would like the `mcC` to be replaced with:

```
   W)
   X)
   Y)
   Z)
```

(The script doesn't have to be in PowerShell; it was the only language I could think of that might be able to implement this.)

Comment: that is what AutoHotKey and AutoIT are about. [*grin*] they both have fairly active forums and are pretty easy to start off with. for instance, the `[*grin*] ` i post so often is an AutoHotKey macro.

Comment: This article is a self-rolled idea of what sounds like AutoIT and similar tools do, if you wanted a pure PS way to do it: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/lukeb/2017/07/12/powershell-expand-aliases/  Might be able to combine it with this: https://johnmj.wordpress.com/2010/11/11/sharepoint-2010-and-localhost-2/